# Typescript can't tell I'm returning early if param is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using TypeScript with React and I'm confused as to why TS can't tell that the below hook returns early if `previous` is `undefined`. It complains about `previous.length` ("Object is possibly undefined"), because it thinks previous could be `undefined` but that cannot be the case as the function would return early if so

```
  function ReactComponent() {
      const previous = usePrevious(value)

      React.useEffect(() => {
        if (previous === undefined) {
           return
        }

        if (previous.length) { // TS says "Object is possibly undefined" despite the return gate above
   
        }
    
      }, [previous])

      return null
  }
```

Oddly, this is only an issue inside a React hook. The below code does not complain...

```
const bar: Array<number> | undefined = undefined

function foo() {
  if (bar === undefined) {
    return
  }

  if (bar.length) { // TS does NOT complain here
    
  }
}
```

My quickfix idea was to use the non-null assertion operator (!) so `previous!.length` but that also complains "Property length does not exist on type never"

**EDIT:** Here's the code for the `usePrevious` hook.

```
export default function usePrevious(value: any) {
  const ref = React.useRef()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value
  }, [value])

  return ref.current
}
```

I can resolve the issue by explicitly stating that the return type of this function is `any`. In other words, by changing `function usePrevious(value: any) { ... }` to `function usePrevious(value: any): any {...}`

Why this fixes it is still a mystery to me, so I'll leave this open for now.

Comment: Does optional chaining operator fix it: `previous?.length` ? Not sure why it complains in one scenario and not the other though

Comment: `previous?.length` complains "Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'". Same as `previous!.length`

Comment: How is `value` declared?

Comment: isn't the return type of `usePrevious` always undefined in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usePrevious` has a ReturnType always `undefined`. Try to type it as:

```
function usePrevious<T>(value: T): T | undefined {
  const ref = React.useRef<T>();
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return ref.current;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works well. I just realized all the places I should be using generics like this For others new to TS, this is the way https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

Damn, that's similar to what I was just writing out @Federkun lol.

```
import { useRef, useEffect, MutableRefObject } from 'react';
type CustomNonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined
    ? never
    : T;
// if generic parameter <T> is a function Type, it extracts the return type
type ReturnTypeOf<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (
    ...args: any
) => infer U
    ? U
    : any;
export default function usePrevious<T, P>(
    value: T,
    previousValue: P
) {
    const refMutable: MutableRefObject<T | undefined> = useRef<T>(); // refMutable: MutableRefObject<T | undefined>
    const refPrevious: MutableRefObject<P | undefined> = useRef<P>(); // refInitial: RefObject<T>
    // use nonullable ! operator to override refMutable.current conditionally undefined
    const NonnullableValue: CustomNonNullable<T> = refMutable!.current! ?? value!;
    const NonnullablePreviousValue: CustomNonNullable<P> = refPrevious!.current! ?? previousValue!;
    useEffect(() => {
        refMutable.current = value ?? undefined;
        refPrevious.current = previousValue ?? undefined;
    }, [value, previousValue]);
    return { NonnullablePreviousValue, NonnullableValue };
}

let y: ReturnTypeOf<typeof usePrevious>;
/**
 * @var y inferred
    let y: {
    NonnullablePreviousValue: unknown;
    NonnullableValue: unknown;
}
 */

export const inferredYObject = () => {
    const { NonnullablePreviousValue, NonnullableValue } = y;
    const trulyPrivateObject = Object.freeze({
        NonnullablePreviousValue,
        NonnullableValue
    } as const);
    return trulyPrivateObject;
};

/**
 * @function inferredYObject has the following type
 *Readonly<{
    readonly NonnullablePreviousValue: unknown;
    readonly NonnullableValue: unknown;
}>
 * this makes it safe at runtime -- prevents XSSmodification
 */
```