# Why does Typescript say X is possibly undefined inside of useMemo when it is never possibly undefined at this point

Tags: typescript

I have the following

```
  const productsWithAddonPrice = useMemo(() => {
    const addonsPrice = addonsSelected
      .map(id => {
        if (addons === undefined) { return 0}
        return addons.find(addon => addon.id === id).price})
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    return [...products].map(p => {
      const productCopy = { ...p };
      productCopy.price += addonsPrice;
      return productCopy;
    });
  }, [addonsSelected, products, addons]);
```

Now as it happens this code works when non-typescript, and addons is by default an empty array further up in the code that wraps useMemo so it is ever actually going to be undefined

```
function useProductAndAddon(products: any[], addons: AddonType[] = []) {
```

but this line

```
return addons.find(addon => addon.id === id).price})
```

gives me the typescript error

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

which given the line above it is

```
if (addons === undefined) { return 0}
```

strikes me as unlikely to be correct, this seems very much related to [Typescript can't tell I'm returning early if param is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67428848/typescript-cant-tell-im-returning-early-if-param-is-undefined)

unfortunately I cannot tell from that question and answer how to solve my current problem, perhaps due to stress clouding my thinking but at any rate I would like some more clarification here if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it I can't find the addon with that id, you get `undefined`

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, `undefined` is returned.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Maybe write something like this?

```
     .map(id => {
        const addon = addons?.find(a => a.id === id);
        return addon?.price ?? 0;
        })
```

Comment: ah thanks, I was confused and thinking it was addons that was undefined because addons was underlined red in VS code and when I moused over it, it said object is possibly undefined. But you're right of course it is not addons but the find, bad tooling had me confused.